# Can I change postgresql data structure?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've just been studying DBMS. There are a lot of programs for DB. (eg. Mysql, MariaDB etc..)
So I wonder in program, for example Postgresql, can I change data structure each table?
Most of programs are using B-tree, however I hope change data structure each table if I can.

Comment: You mean you want to change the primary, physical organization on disk? Well, you have to look at the documentation what options Postgres offers here. But it's open source, so you can change anything you like, even if it isn't currently offered. But AFAIK none of the mentioned DBMS uses B trees for tables. The standard is a simple heap. B trees are used for indexes. Though one could theoretically use B trees for primary organization too.

Comment: Thank you. My first language is not English, so there were confusing by word. As you mentioned, I was able to know that searched by 'indexes'. (TMI I'm Korean:) Thank you every comments!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking if you can change the table structure like adding or removing columns, altering the data type of a column, if yes, then it is possible.

> Refer here for [postgresql](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-alter-table/) syntax

> Refer here for [SQL Server/MS SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) syntax

> Refer here for [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) syntax

Comment: No I mean literally data structure(no table structure) for example, change B-tree to Gist, SP-GiST, Hash etc.. But thank you I think I can find the answer from your answer.

Comment: @Eugene what you have listed there are types of index, not types of table. To change an index type, just drop it and re-create it with a different type.